# Split MS-Access reports into pdf's

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got the following VBA code from the web a while ago:

```
Private Sub btnCreatePDF_Click()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFilename As String
    MyPath = "D:\reports\"
        MyFilename = "KS1.pdf"
    'Open report preview and auto-save it as a PDF
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_KS1", acViewPreview
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, False 'Change false to true here to auto-open the saved PDF
    'Close the previewed report
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Rpt_KS1"
End Sub
```

It was for use in MS Access to create a single pdf of reports (containing up to 30 pages) and works fine for what i needed. However, i now need to split the report into  the 30 or so pages and create a pdf for each of the pages. Any idea how this can be done?
I have a 'username' in the report or can add a unique ID if this helps to split them etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 4th parameter (WhereCondition) of [Docmd.OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx). With the WhereCondition, do exactly what you would normally do when adding a Where to your query, only don't include the word Where. This will make the report only display records that match the WhereCondition.

Retrieve your list of unique identifiers into some sort of a collection, or recordset then do a loop. This example assumes that you have them in a collection called uniqueIds and will almost definitely require some modification by you.

```
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFilename As String
MyPath = "D:\reports\"    
'Loop structure may vary depending on how you obtain values
For each uniqueId in uniqueIds
    MyFilename = "KS1" & uniqueId & ".pdf"
'Open report preview and auto-save it as a PDF
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_KS1", acViewPreview, , "uniqueField = " & uniqueID
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, False
'Close the previewed report
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Rpt_KS1"
Next uniqueId
```

Strictly speaking, this may not result in a different PDF for each page. But it will generate a different PDF for each uniqueID, which might be every page depending on your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the basic idea here, so i created a recordset and, altho I kept getting an error with "For each" on the loop, i went with "Do Until rs.EOF" and it worked. BUT! now the problem is, altho the report gets split into pdf's with each page from the reports being a separate pdf (just as i wanted), the reports in the pdf's  are actually blank now! Any suggestions on what might be happening here?

Comment: I can only guess that when you use the filter to bring up your report you are inadvertantly providing a value to which no records match. Perhaps you have trailing spaces or something in your uniqueID or uniqueField. I would investigate that for resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. No matter what i try I can't get it working and time is moving on, so i'll take a look at a different approach.

Comment: @detjo That's sad. If it were practical I would suggest posting it somewhere and letting me take a look, but I doubt it is. Good luck.

Comment: Hi - I got it working! :)
I went back to what you said and, where i had:
DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_KS1", acViewPreview, , "uniqueField = " & uniqueID
I needed the end bit to be: "uniqueField = '" & uniqueID &"'"
Daniel, you're a star. Thanks very much for your time.